Problems deploying Firebase Functions from Google Cloud Build
The instructions to deploy 'hosting' seemed to be super simple, just:
args: ['deploy', '--project=project-id', '--only=hosting']

Now, I wanted to deploy hosting and functions, so I stripped the '--only=hosting' but this failed because:

the venv was not found (Error: Failed to find location of Firebase Functions SDK. Did you forget to run '. "/workspace/XXX/functions/venv/bin/activate" && python3.12 -m pip install -r requirements.txt'?)
environment variables from the cloud build step definition were missing (Error: In non-interactive mode but have no value for the following environment variables)


This is the cloudbuild.yml I ended up using to deploy my firebase function using google cloud build:
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/XXX/firebase
    env:
      - ENV1=1
    args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        set  &&
        env | grep -E "ENV1|SECRETENV" > functions/.env &&
        python3 -m venv functions/venv &&
        . functions/venv/bin/activate &&
        python -m pip install -r functions/requirements.txt &&
        firebase deploy --project=XXXX
    dir: blah
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    secretEnv:
      - SECRETENV
timeout: 600s
availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
    - versionName: projects/XXX/secrets/XXXX/versions/latest
      env: SECRETENV

